# How to add class to parent a tag with a sub menu

Tags: menus, walker

I have been trying to add a class to the parent a tag of a sub menu using a custom walker. The current walker I am using adds the class to the parent `<li>`, does anybody know how to adjust this to add the class to the parent `<a>` tag instead.

**Here is the existing walker I am using:**

```
class My_Walker_Nav_Menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu{
  public function display_element($el, &$children, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output){
    $id = $this->db_fields['id'];    

    if(isset($children[$el->$id]))
      $el->classes[] = 'toggle-sub-nav closed';    

    parent::display_element($el, $children, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output);
  }
}
```

**Here is the code that is output:**

[image: screen shot of current code output]

**Here is the code that I am aiming for:**

[image: Screen shot of desired code output with class applied to the a tag]

Comment: Any specific reason for that? You can always add the class to the parent `li` and apply CSS rules to the nested `a` using `.toggle-sub-nav > a {`.

Comment: Hi, I am converting a responsive html/css/jquery template I built to wordpress and I require a class applied to that tag.

Comment: You can use jQuery `.hasClass()` to check if the parent `li` has the `menu-item-has-children` class and if it does add your classes to the nested `a` using `.addClass()`.

Comment: Thank you. Ideally I would like this handled by php, do you know how to do this?

Comment: Please don't post _screenshots of code_. Post the actual code (current/desired) as [edit] to your question.

Comment: @AshleyBriscoe: Have you added the `array( 'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu,` to the `wp_nav_menu()`: 
`wp_nav_menu( array( 'walker' => new My_Walker_Nav_Menu, 'theme_location' => 'site_menu', 'menu_class' => 'my-site-menu' ) );`?

Comment: I have, it's not the array that is the issue, it is applying the class to the parent Li not the parent a

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply add this code snippet in your theme's functions.php file.**

```
/* Add classes and other attributes to the anchor tags if list item is a parent */

add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_class_to_items_link', 10, 3 );

function add_class_to_items_link( $atts, $item, $args ) {
  // check if the item has children
  $hasChildren = (in_array('menu-item-has-children', $item->classes));
  if ($hasChildren) {
    // add the desired attributes:
    $atts['class'] = 'your-custom-class'; //This is the main concern according to the question
    $atts['id'] = 'your-custom-id'; //Optional
    $atts['data-toggle'] = 'dropdown'; //Optional
    $atts['data-target'] = '#'; //Optional
  }
  return $atts;
}
```

Comment: HI, welcome on WPSE. You should edit your answer and add more content as source code to understand your solution. Why and how it works.